# AT command for change IMSI android

Tags: android, command, at-command, imei

I'm change IMEI using AT command in engineer menu

```
AT +EGMR=1,7,”XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX”
```

How i can change IMSI?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMSI is NOT the ICC ID ("the ID of the SIM-card") !

The [International Mobile Subscriber Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_mobile_subscriber_identity) (IMSI) is formatted from:

- [Mobile Country Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code) (MCC)
- Mobile Network Code (MNC)
- Mobile Subscription Identification Number (MSIN)

But yes, it's all programmed to the SIM.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done. The IMSI is the ID of the Sim-card, and it hard-coded to the SIM.